# upload audio file with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, multipart

i am trying to upload audio file to server with retrofit2. after sending request the response is :
"message": "(1007) Unsupported audio format"

these are information that i'm sent with PostMan :

[image]

[image]

here my code :

InterFace :

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("audiofile")
    Call<ResponseModel> upload(@Header("X-SessionID") String account , @Part MultipartBody.Part file , @Query("path") String address);
```

and

```
 RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), file);
        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("voice", file.getName(), requestFile);
        String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
        RequestBody description =
                RequestBody.create(
                        okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

        Call<ResponseModel> response = requestInterface.upload(session , body , file.getName());
        response.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseModel> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseModel> response) {

                Log.d("server-", "onResponse: " + new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d("server-", "onResponse: " + t);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski where am i wrong ? please help me

Comment: it's seems to be the API response, you need to know which formats are valid to send.

Comment: @Alexandre i think that MediaType should be change 
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("mp3/*"), file);
i don't know which format should i write ?
i know that server accepts mp3 files.

Comment: @TheMJ where is this message "...unsupported..."? It always return 200 ok ?

Comment: @Alexandre yes that's right